# Symfony call a bundle in an other bundle

Tags: bundle, symfony

I'm trying to call a method of one of my bundles in my main bundle, but it returns me an error. I did something wrong for sure, but I don't know what.

The error:

> Call to a member function has() on null

My code in my MainBundle, calling my ReviewBundle :

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $reviewController = new \ReviewBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
        $reviews = $reviewController->listAction();
        return new Response($reviews);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the listAction should already return a Response, so just return it :

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $reviewController = new \ReviewBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
        $reviews = $reviewController->listAction();
        return $reviews;
}
```

Comment: it worked ! thank you so much ! (sorry for the delay, I gave up until I ran into your answer that I didn't see before)